# Calendar DAX Table

Tags: powerbi, dax

Creating a new calendar table within power bi using the below DAX script and it gives me what I am looking for.

```
Calendar = 
var _Calendar = 
CALENDAR("1/1/2015","31/12/2022")
Return
ADDCOLUMNS(
_Calendar,
"Year",YEAR([Date]),
"MonthNumber",MONTH([Date]),
"Month",FORMAT([Date], "mmm"),
"Quarter", "QTR" & FORMAT([Date], "Q"),
"QuarterNumber", FORMAT([Date], "Q"),
"MonthYearNumber", FORMAT([Date], "yy mm"),
"Month Year",FORMAT([Date], "mm yyyy")
)
```

However, if I want to look at only the Month in a line chart the data type is in text so in random order rather than Calendar (Jan, Feb, Mar, Etc) and I've tried changing the Data type from text to date but it gives an error.

[Graph Capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccCCq.png)

What do I need to change in order for the format to be correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep the data type as text but add a sort column and use Month Number as the sort column.

Comment: I managed to get this working, thanks.
However, because the Month column is still as text and not date Data Type it does not allow me to create a forecast within the line chart. 
Take it that there's no way to amend this?

Comment: You can use only 'Month' of Date Hierarchy in the [Date] column for the forecast.